# mysql increment against another column

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Here is my Products table.

```
+---------+------------+-----------+
| item_id | item_order | item_name |
+---------+------------+-----------+
|      10 |            | Item x    |
|      12 |            | Item b    |
|      33 |            | Item j    |
|      39 |            | Item k    |
+---------+------------+-----------+
```

I want to run a sql query in phpMyAdmin so that item_order will increment as item_id number decreases. I want to arrange products on my Featured Products page by item_order. At a later time I'll rearrange numbers in 'item_order' column to give certain products more prominence, but for now here is how table will look after query update...

```
+---------+------------+-----------+
| item_id | item_order | item_name |
+---------+------------+-----------+
|      10 |          4 | Item x    |
|      12 |          3 | Item b    |
|      33 |          2 | Item j    |
|      39 |          1 | Item k    |
+---------+------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Why would you need this? You could just do an `order by item_id desc` to reverse the sorting order.

Comment: Can you add some reasoning? It might be easier to do this a different way. *edit* @MarcB beat me to it :)

Comment: @ShivanRaptor: Not *necessarily*, but it certainly appears as though it might be from the information given in the question.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
SELECT *, (
  SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Products pd WHERE pd.item_id >= p.item_id
) item_order
FROM Products p
```